# FOC HJB show only one solution in R for my domain

Tags: linear-algebra

I am working on a macroeconomic model and I need to derive a First Order condition from a HJB equation. Simplified, I can write the FOC as $ac+bc^{1/2}-1 = 0$ and want to solve for $c$. I have $a>0$, $b>0$, $c>0$, all in $\mathbb{R}$. With my (apparently naive calculus) I derive the general solution
\begin{align}
c_1 = \frac{\sqrt{4ab^2+b^4}+2a+b^2}{2a^2}
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
c_2 = \frac{-\sqrt{4ab^2+b^4}+2a+b^2}{2a^2}.
\end{align}

However, for my domains, that is $a>0$, $b>0$ over the reals, the only correct solution is $c_2$ (says Wolfram Alpha, plots, etc.), but I fail to show this in a general form. I assume I miss some necessary assumptions in my calculus, but cannot figure out what because I always end with the two solutions. Also, Wolfram Alpha does not provide a step for step solution when specifying over the reals. I would be forever thankful if someone could help me out